# Find recurring element from list

Tags: python

```
list=['A', 'R', 'I','J','I','T','T']

def reccuring():
    count=0
    list1=[]
    for i in list:
        if list.count(i)>1:
            list1.append(i)
    return list1
reccuring()
```

OutPut

```
['I', 'I', 'T', 'T']
```

I am getting the recurring elements as many times as present in the list. What modification do I have to do to get the recurring elements only once?

Thank You

Comment: make `list1` a `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better name your variables and use a `set`

```
values = ['A', 'R', 'I', 'J', 'I', 'T', 'T']

def reccuring():
    count = 0
    result = set()
    for value in values:
        if value not in result and values.count(value) > 1:
            result.add(value)
    return result

reccuring()
```

Comment: may I please know why the list doesn't return only the element that is recurring?

Comment: @user20666007 what is your expected result ?

Comment: I want   'I', 'J'

Comment: I mean 'I' and 'T'. Only the recurring letters.

Comment: @user20666007 the outout is `{'I', 'T'}` I don't understand what is the problem ?